# multiple 'imageviews' in jframe

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, panel

hi all i am trying to add multiple components to my jframe. but i cant seem to get it to work.

```
private void initGUI() {
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setUndecorated(true);

    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);

    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.5f);
    setLocation(ini.getButtonsX(), ini.getButtonsY());
    setSize(ini.getButtonsW(), ini.getButtonsH());

    setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    ImageView baron = new ImageView("image/nashor.png", 50, 50);
    baron.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
    ImageView test = new ImageView("image/dragon.png", 50, 50);
    test.setBounds(50, 150, 50, 50);

    panel.add(baron);
    panel.add(test);

    panel.setBounds(0, 0, ini.getButtonsW(), ini.getButtonsH());

    add(panel);



}
```

my ImageView is a class that extends a JPanel which paints a image.

at this point only nashor is painted

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"but i cant seem to get it to work."` may not tell us enough to allow us to help you well. Please tell us more such as what happens.

Comment: I will say that as a general rule, you should avoid using null layouts that you are almost always better off using some of the layout managers.

Comment: You want to add multiple images to your panel?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you have your JPanel panel use a GridLayout, not a null layout, and that you not set your ImageView sizes but rather make sure that the class has a `getPreferredSize()` method override that makes sense, that returns a Dimension of the appropriate size. Then if you call `pack()` on your JFrame after adding components, the layout managers will take care of sizing things for you.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Init extends JFrame{
    JPanel view = new JPanel();
    JMenuBar mBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem mItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem mItemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    JTextField txtPath = new JTextField();

    BufferedImage myPicture;
    File filePath;
    String path;

    public Init(){
        mBar.add(menu);
        menu.add(mItemOpen);
        menu.addSeparator();
        menu.add(mItemExit);
        setJMenuBar(mBar);
        txtPath.setEditable(false);
        mItemOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                filePath = fc.getSelectedFile();
                path = filePath.getPath();
                txtPath.setText(path);
                try {
                    //view.removeAll();
                    myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
                    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
                    view.add(picLabel);
                    revalidate();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(view),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(txtPath,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setTitle(".:My Picture Viewer:.");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //pack();
        setSize(1024,768);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new Init();
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

[image]